# Flutter: How to navigate native camera app

Tags: flutter, camera, nativeapplication

i want to shot a photo in my app. I am using [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) library. But this library does not have **auto focus**, **flash** and **zoom** feature. These features are important to me. I also tried [lamp](https://pub.dev/packages/lamp) and [flutter_better_camera](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_better_camera) libraries. What is your suggestion? My question is, can I redirect it to a native app when I click a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to this. I directed it to the camera using the [ImagePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) library.